# Relations between optimization versions of k-coloring and max-k-colorable induced subgraph.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am a tourist of Graph theory but I have this problem I am trying to solve, part of a research objective connected to quantum computing.

I am trying to understand the relationship between:

the problem of minimizing the number of conflicts (edges) by using k colors to color the vertices of a graph $G$ (problem 1)

and

the identification of the largest induced subgraph of $G$ which is k-colorable (problem 2).

In particular, I would like to know if a solution to problem 2 can be found if I have access to all the solutions of problem 1.

In particular, I was interested in knowing if the following is true:

> for at least one solution of problem 1, if I identify a minimum-vertex
>   cover $V^\prime$ of the vertices that are in conflict - then I can
>   remove $V^\prime$ from $G$ and get a valid solution to problem 2.

I am trying to find a counterexample to prove if this is false.
Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Did you intend to let $V'$ be a [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) of the *edges* that are in conflict? Then removing those vertices (and their incident edges) will ensure you have a feasible $k$-coloring of an induced subgraph of $G$.

Comment: @ChrisJones I have understand so.

Answer (score 1):

> AR: I thought about this question a bit and I hope it can be answered by forces of MSE users, because it may be not so hard, but it needs different ideas and approaches. Also it gives a unique occasion to find an application of such abstract and combinatorial branch of mathematics as graph coloring is such deep natural science as quantum computing, so I am happy to support it by finding at last a good use for a few of my reputation points. :-)

Thus my bounty increased the number of question views to 37 and a part  of them are mine. :-)  But I don’t give up. In September starts my regular season of intensive graph theory collaboration with the group of [Sascha Wolff](http://www1.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/en/staff/wolff_alexander) in Würzburg, and I’m going to propose your problem for our group. I hope it would be helpful because these guys are true graph theorists whereas I am a mathematician. :-) If we'll found an answer then I'll write it here. :-) Currently I can only say that for $k=1$ the answer is positive, but this is trivial. There is only one solution of Problem 1, and the largest induced one-colorable subgraph is the largest independent set, which is equivalent to a complement to a smallest vertex cover of the set of vertices with non-zero degree.

Comment: However, the largest independent set cannot efficiently be found... which is too bad and makes me suspect one cannot efficiently (optimally) solve Problem 2 for larger $k$.

Comment: @ChrisJones Recall that according to the conditions we already have an access to all the solutions of Problem 1 (quantum computations are  much more effective than classical algorithms).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your fact is true:

> There is a $k$-coloring $\varphi$ of the vertices such that: if $S$ is a minimum vertex cover of the violated edges of $\varphi$, then $\overline S$ is a $k$-colorable induced subgraph of $G$ of largest possible size.

The relation between vertex covers and independent sets is actually extremely tight. Let $\varphi$ be any coloring of the vertices, and let $\widetilde G = (V, \widetilde E)$ be a new graph with the same vertex set, and edge set $\widetilde E$ equal to the violated edges of $\varphi$. Then vertex covers in $\widetilde G$ (i.e. covers of the violations of $\varphi$ in $G$) are exactly complements of independent sets in $\widetilde G$ (i.e. $k$-colored induced subgraphs of $G$). This implies that complementing a smallest vertex cover (across all colorings) will give a largest $k$-colorable subgraph (across all colorings).

It doesn't seem feasible to solve Problem 2 using solutions to Problem 1, however. Let's say a solution $\varphi$ to Problem 1 is a $k$-coloring of the graph that minimizes the number of conflicts. Problem 2 asks for the largest induced subgraph that's $k$-colorable, and as we saw above that's the complement of a minimum vertex cover of $\widetilde G$ for some coloring $\varphi'$. There are two problems: one, there's no efficient algorithm to find a minimum vertex cover of the violations of $\varphi$ if we're given $\varphi$ (it's [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Exact_evaluation)); two, the minimum vertex cover for $\varphi$ may not even be the smallest possible minimum vertex cover across all colorings.

Comment: The essence of Ventu’s conjecture is that $\varphi$ is not an arbitrary $k$-coloring of the vertices, but minimizing the number of conflicts (edges). Next we take the minimum over all such colorings.

Comment: Nevertheless, I’ll give to you the  bounty because otherwise it will be lost. But feel free to join to our quest for the answer.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. The conjecture seems extremely false! Let me try and prove it.

Comment: @ChrisJones did you have any luck in proving it wrong?

Comment: How about this: extend the min-conflict-2-coloring to weighted graphs. Take a collection of triangles that share a single common vertex $v$. Edges involving $v$ are weight 2, the other edge of each triangle has weight 1. Unique min-2-coloring: color $v$ red and every other vertex blue, and the conflict graph is a collection of disjoint edges. On the other hand, the maximal 2-colorable subgraph is everything except $v$. I'm not sure how to get rid of the weights, but probably there is a way to replace each weight-2 edge by a small gadget.